# Sporadic redirects on secondary magento store page

Tags: magento, redirect, magento-1.7

Recently transferred my Magento 1.7 store to a new host, and started having a frustrating problem.

We've got the store sitting behind a login shell - you can see it at http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com. Base exchange takes you to the root store (/magento/), and the gearlocker login takes you to a secure sub-store (/magento/gearlocker/).

The problem is, ever since transferring to the new host, /magento/gearlocker/ is sporadically redirecting to /magento/. I can only reproduce it 1 in every 10 times, but customers are constantly complaining that they can't access the secure store for this reason.

I've also noticed that if I turn off the security and have clients navigate to /magento/gearlocker/ directly, it seems to fix the problem for most - they no longer get the redirect after logging in. Only a few of them still have the error, and they're all PC users on various browsers.

I've set up a demo login for stack:
https://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/login.php
U: stack_login
P: thanks

I doubt it's an issue with the base url or base link url, otherwise the error would be much more consistent. I've gone through magento's official tutorials and made sure the secondary store was set up properly (remember, it was working fine on the old host). I also know it's not anything to do with the login shell - all it does is validate the user's login and redirect to /magento/gearlocker/.

Can anyone reproduce this error? Can anyone tell me what's going on, or how I might fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: All your links are linked to `/magento/skin/gearlocker/` and redirects to `/magento/gearlocker/`.. You have the wrong base link I guess.

Comment: Thanks @KalpeshMehta - just caught that myself. That was the result of a tweak from this morning though, not the source of the error I'm looking for.